# Laravel, export my Events to Google Calendar (or any other popular Calendar app?)

Tags: laravel-5, calendar, google-calendar-api

I have an app where users sign up for events that last from specific time (1pm - 2pm) on specific day (30th of May 2016.).

Is it possible to offer to the user to import those events to their Google Calendar by pressing the button?

Are there any other popular calendar apps that I should cover too?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a library that makes it easy to interact with Google-calendar

https://github.com/spatie/laravel-google-calendar

If you want to do the integration by yourself you should read through the [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/create-events).

Comment: Thatnk's, thats probably it but give me some time to check it out and I'll mark it as right answer.
Do you know of any similar apps that I should include next to GoogleCalendar? Also have you used the spatie's library?

Comment: I've not used the library but I've worked with the Google API directly and it's really easy to work with. The range of apps to aim for depends on what platform you're aiming for. If it's a mobile-app it should implement some iOs calendar as well.